# Run array check more than array count in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I load such XML files for check of full sequences into Java and get a value from the XML. This value is saved into an array.

Then I will check which sequences are missing in the files, so I have to sort the values and check the minimum value against the first array value. Then check the minimum value + 1 against the second array value and so on.

The for loop, I can only run how often, are values saved into array. In example it's 6 times. But I need to run it 8 times.

Example:

```
XML files with SequenceNumber from 68 to 75.
XML files with SequenceNumber 73 and 74 are missing.
```

The check have to be done 8 times (68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75) but it's only perfomed 6 times (I have only 6 files / 6 array values).

How can it be done to run the check if SequenceNumber is ok or missing how often its needed, so from minimum to maximum value?

```
ArrayList seqNrList = new ArrayList<>();
seqNrList.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("SequenceNumber").item(0).getTextContent());
Collections.sort(seqNrList);
int seqNr; //currentValue
int instanceCounter = Integer.valueOf((String) Collections.min(seqNrList));

int seqsizemin = Integer.valueOf((String) Collections.min(seqNrList));
int seqsizemax = Integer.valueOf((String) Collections.max(seqNrList));
int seqruns = seqsizemax - seqsizemin + 1;

System.out.println("first Sequence: " + Collections.min(seqNrList));
System.out.println("last Sequence: " + Collections.max(seqNrList));
System.out.println("max runs: " + seqruns);

for (int i = 0; i < seqNrList.size(); i++) {
    seqNr = Integer.valueOf((String) seqNrList.get(i));
    if (instanceCounter == seqNr) {
        System.out.println("Sequence " + seqNrList.get(i) + " ok");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sequence " + instanceCounter + " Missing");
    }
    instanceCounter++;
}
```

When I run it this way, I got the following result:

```
first Sequence: 68
last Sequence: 75
max runs: 8
Sequence 68 ok
Sequence 69 ok
Sequence 70 ok
Sequence 71 ok
Sequence 72 ok
Sequence 73 Missing
```

expected is:

```
first Sequence: 68
last Sequence: 75
max runs: 8
Sequence 68 ok
Sequence 69 ok
Sequence 70 ok
Sequence 71 ok
Sequence 72 ok
Sequence 73 Missing
Sequence 73 Missing
Sequence 75 ok
```

How can this be done? Whats my error at the moment?

Thx in Advance
Toni

Comment: Variable names should start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping from you minimum value to your maximum value and search with contains method like this:

```
for (int i = seqsizemin;i<=seqsizemax;i++) {
        if (SeqNrList.contains(i+"")) {
            System.out.println("Sequence " + i + " ok");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sequence " + i + " Missing");
        }
    }
```